# Where is the correct place to initialize BigDecimal limit when using Puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I have a rails initializer that sets the limit on Big Decimal

```
BigDecimal.limit(20)
```

This is executed and seems to set the limit properly.

But when a web request comes in (I am using Puma), the limit does not appear to be set on the thread that handles the request.  The limit is set to 0 which is the default.

Is there somewhere else I should be setting the limit?

If you want to reproduce:

create a brand new rails app and add an initializer that sets limit

```
BigDecimal.limit(20)
puts "*** Set #{BigDecimal.limit}"
```

in your application controller add

```
before_action :check_big_decimal

def check_big_decimal
  puts "***request #{BigDecimal.limit}"
end
```

start your server, refresh page and make a request

You should see it set to 20 but then it is back to 0 when the request comes in.

Comment: I was looking at this the other day. I believe the issue is that you're setting the limit in a different thread (the Rails main thread). No requests are handled within that thread so you never see the limit. Ways to get around this can be using a Middleware that sets it on every request or a before_action in your ApplicationController. To be honest, I think you should do neither because it has substantial downsides (e.g. the limit not being set in your tasks).

Comment: As a general remark, you might want to reconsider if you want to do this in the first place. There is a method `BigDecimal#save_limit`[1] which can be used to only set the limit within a block. It'd probably best practice to wrap the critical business logic in such a block. One of the main benefits is that it's 100% clear to the reader that we're dealing with a different than default precision.

[1]: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-save_limit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got an answer from the Rails [community](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/39512)

Basic gist is:

*This happens because Ruby stores the BigDecimal limit in thread local storage.
When e.g. Puma starts a new thread to handle a request, the new thread can't access the BigDecimal limit set in the initial thread.*

Answer (score 0):

A hacky and not recommended way is by monkey patching the class. You can add this in an initializer

```
class BigDecimal
  def self.limit(val = 25)
    25
  end
end
```

The question is, do you really really want to limit to 25 everywhere? if yes, then you can try this as a LAST RESORT, because I'm not sure about the side effects of hardcoding that value (and overriding that method at all)

Comment: Your suggestion gave me the idea to override the property to see if I could tell where it is being reset... I can see it called when I set it, but it is never called anywhere else!